# How do I correctly include Moment.js and Chart.js with RequireJS when I want to create charts with time scales?

Tags: requirejs, chart.js, momentjs

I use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to include [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create charts with time scales.

I found an example at https://codepen.io/adrianhurt/pen/dXRRoL to include both but it doesn't seems to be the correct way.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min',
    moment: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment',
    chartjs: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    chartjs: {
      deps: [ 'moment' ]
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
require(['jquery', 'moment', 'chartjs'], function($ ,moment, Chart) ...
```

When I create a chart the exception `Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale. Download at https://momentjs.com` will be thrown.

Therefore my question is, *how do I correctly include Moment.js and Chart.js with RequireJS when I want to create charts with time scales?*

Please note that the Chart.js bundle is not an alternative for me, because I need Moment.js also separately.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ: Found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the solution at https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4987.

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'moment': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment',
    'chartjs': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart'
  }
})

define('moment-adapter', ['moment'], function(moment) {
  window.moment = moment;
  return moment;
})

require(['moment-adapter', 'chartjs'], function(moment, Chart) {
   ...
})
```